# sslv3 alert handshake failure when trying to create a new Symfony project

Tags: openssl, symfony, centos5

I have installed symfony 3.2 in CentOS.

Then I tried:

```
symfony new contratos3.0
```

but this error is shown:

```
[GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException]                                 
  cURL error 35: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Use TLS 1.0 or above, and use [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)

Comment: How to make symfony binary to use TLS 1.0 instead?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you are on Mac OS and you need a different version of cURL. Try:

```
brew install curl
brew link curl --force
```

to get the one for Mac OS.
See this reference:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/how-to-fix-curl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure

Comment: No.... this is Linux CentOS 5p